# Why is my regex string not matching as a whole while individual components of the whole do match?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to use a regular expression to match a string of the type `16 June 1997`. The pattern isn't that complicated, and when I try and match individual components of the larger regex string, it matches just fine. But for some reason, I'm having trouble matching the entire regex string. I'm honestly at a loss here, so any tips are appreciated.

```r
library(stringr)

## Good
str_detect("16 June 1997", "[0-9]{1,2}[\\s]{1,1}[January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December]")
#> [1] TRUE

## Good
str_detect("16 June 1997", "[\\s]{1,1}[0-9]{4,4}")
#> [1] TRUE

## Good
str_detect("16 June 1997", "[January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December]{1,1}[\\s]{1,1}[0-9]{4,4}")
#> [1] TRUE

## Bad
str_detect("16 June 1997", "[0-9]{1,2}[\\s]{1,1}[January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December]{1,1}[\\s]{1,1}[0-9]{4,4}")
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: You're using a character class `[]` instead of an alternation `()` for the month name. So you're only checking for one character in the set instead of the entire month name. Note that you don't need `{1,1}` it is implicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex format is a bit weird.

You don't have to specify quantifiers if you just want to match one character, and you can just put a single number to have a specific number of instances of a character.

Also, the months should be an OR, which would go in parentheses.

This works:

```
str_detect("1 June 1997", "[0-9]{1,2}\\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\\s[0-9]{4}")
```

Also, be careful where you use this, if you're using this to parse user input, you might run into some trouble because you're assuming you're only gonna have a single space character surrounding the month.